# How to combine or use batteries having different capacities?

Tags: batteries, parallel, powerbanks

I know that batteries can't be connected in parallel even though they are the same type (eg. Li-ion) if they have different capacities. I have several of those and want to use them to make a desk light, a power bank, etc. Is there any way to use them safely?

Should I use every single battery in a different project because of the different capacities? If so, how much is the maximum capacity difference that would prevent me from combining cells?

Comment: The way to do it would cost more money in electronic load balancing components than it would for buying a new set of identical batteries.

Comment: Why do think batterires cannot be **paralleled**? he problems you may be thinking are generally related to putting different kind of cells in **series**.

Comment: "I know that batteries can't be connected in parallel even though they are the same type (eg. Li-ion) if they have different capacities. " Who says? If they have the same voltage they can be connected in parallel.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy thank you. I watched several videos and all of them mentioned that I should combine the batteries parallel only if they are the same mAh. They were combining 18650 li-ion batteries. It is also written in [some websites too] (https://battlebornbatteries.com/100ah-batteries-in-line-with-my-270ah-batteries/#:~:text=We%20strongly%20recommend%20you%20DO,and%20voltage%20discrepancy%20between%20batteries.)

Comment: Do you both mean that 2 18650 Li-ion batteries can be used together by connecting parallel (one is 1000 mAh the other is 2000 mAh)?

Comment: @ÖmerGÜZEL Batteries with different mAh capacities should not be connected _in series_ but may be connected _in parallel_, if you first ensure that their voltages are identical (not just their nominal voltages, but their actual voltages). If they are different mAh capacities, either charge them according to the maximum charge current of the largest one (not the sum of both) -- it will take longer to charge them, or charge them separately -- you will need to bring them to the same voltage before reconnecting them.